# Exoplanet Simulator non-zero status error

Tags: python, simulation

I am attempting to use a recent simulator, ExoPlaSim, which can model terrestrial exoplanets within the habitable zone. After pip installing the program, I attempted to run the following basic program, directly copy-pasted from the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import exoplasim as exo

toi700d = exo.Model(workdir="toi700d_run",modelname="TOI-700d",
                    ncpus=4,resolution="T21",outputtype=".npz")
toi700d.configure(startemp=3480.0, flux=1167.0,                           # Stellar parameters
                  eccentricity=0.,obliquity=0.,fixedorbit=True,           # Orbital parameters
                  synchronous=True,rotationperiod=37.426,                 # Rotation
                  radius=1.19,gravity=11.9,aquaplanet=True,               # Bulk properties
                  pN2=1.47*(1-360e-6),pCO2=1.47*360e-6,ozone=False,       # Atmosphere
                  timestep=30.0,snapshots=720,physicsfilter="gp|exp|sp")  # Model dynamics
toi700d.exportcfg()
toi700d.run(years=10,crashifbroken=True)
```

This results in the following error trace:
[image]
I'm not quite sure what this error trace means or how I can resolve it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's interesting is, that's not the correct format for `subproess.run`.   Since they're supplying a complete string, It shouldn't be in brackets. That never should have worked.  Can you, from a command line, run that exact command?  If you can configure and build the library yourself, then the software shouldn't need to.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi, I'm just familiar with the basics of the command line. Could you clarify a bit? The entire error trace is a bit foreign to me.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hm, interesting. I run that command and it states:
* Sorry - didn't find any FORTRAN-90 compiler      *
* Please install one (e.g. gfortran or g95)        *
* or update list of known compilers in this script *

Comment: Did the ExoPlaSim module install correctly? According to the instructions, a Fortran  compiler is a requirement.

Comment: It looks like a failure at a makefile somewhere, likely due to not finding a Fortran compiler (according to your last comment). That's where I'd investigate.

Comment: @MatthewHartman Hi, I've revised my question. Tim's suggestion paved some progress, but I'm still running up against an error trace.

Comment: According to the documentation: 
"The crashifbroken flag simply means that if something goes wrong, the model will crash in a slightly cleaner, Pythonic way. Note that a problem with the postprocessor will get flagged as a crash just like an actual model crash–in most cases, the model is salvageable if you figure out what went wrong with the postprocessor."

Comment: @MatthewHartman Thanks for shedding some insight into the error trace. So in essence the author of the library leaves figuring out what went wrong with the postprocessor to the user? How am I even supposed to figure that out?

Comment: OK, so exoplasim needs the Gnu FORTRAN compiler.  Have you installed that?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I wrote that I installed it above in the revised question.

Comment: I certainly have no clue.  You may have to ask the exoplasim user commiunity.